# Passing variable from view to controller ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get the id of a clicked button and then send that `buttonId` to the variable `categoryId` in the action `AddItem` of the controller `ItemController` using ajax but I am relatively new to ajax and am not sure where I am going wrong.

html code in view:

```
<button id="1" onclick=" buttonClicked(this.id)">button1</button>
```

javascript code in view that gets the id of the button clicked:

```
function buttonClicked(buttonId) {
   $.ajax({
     url: '<%: Url.Action("ItemController, AddItem")%>',
     data: { 'id': buttonId },
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
   });
}
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItem(int buttonId)
 {
   var categoyId = Convert.ToString(buttonId);
   return View();
 }
```